# Running into 404 error with URL Dispatcher

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

This is my url.py in WebFetcher

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('Fetcher.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my url.py in Fetcher

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('page_objects/', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')
]
```

this is my form

```
<form action="{% url 'page_objects' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is the name of my function in views

```
def page_objects(request):
```

I am getting 404 error saying
Using the URLconf defined in WebFetcher.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='home']
page_ojects [name='page_objects']
admin/
^media/(?P.*)$
The current path, WebFetcher/page_ojects, didn't match any of these.

I ready all the documentation on the URL Dispatcher and I could not find anything that looks wrong with my code. I hope it is just a syntax error. If you think more of my code will be helpful, comment and I will edit this post.

Edit 1:

I updated my WebFetcher urls.py and my Fetcher urls.py per Daniel's suggest.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from Fetcher import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('WebFetcher/', include('Fetcher.urls')),
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)



from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('page_objects/', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')
]
```

Now the 404 error I am getting is

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebFetcher/WebFetcher/WebFetcher/page_objects/
Using the URLconf defined in WebFetcher.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

WebFetcher/ page_objects/ [name='page_objects']
[name='home']
admin/
^media/(?P.*)$
The current path, WebFetcher/WebFetcher/page_objects/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Can you share all of your urls.py files? Is the path you shared above in a specific app with its own urls.py?

Comment: I added in all of the urls.py code

Comment: You are tring to go to this path in your browser `WebFetcher/page_objects` but you did not specify any `WebFetcher` root. You can either try to go to just `/page_objects` or preprend your path in your urls.py with `WebFetcher/`

Comment: Current my views file path is WebFetcher/Fetcher/views.py . Sorry if this is a simple solution, I had it working with a static form action with /views before. I think this is what you are saying "  path('WebFetcher/page_objects', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')  " however my views.py is in the Fetcher folder. Sorry my files names are not more unique :) . It seems like to me no matter what I changed the webpage thinks I want WebFetcher/WebFetcher at the start of my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to `http://mywebsite/page_objects` instead of `http://mywebsite/WebFetcher/page_objects`.

If you want to have the `page_objects` url nested under `WebFetcher` then you can do this to your urls.py:

MyProject/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('WebFetcher/', include('Fetcher.urls')), # add the prefix here
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Fetcher/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('page_objects/', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')
]
```

Note: your home page will now be at `http://mywebsite/WebFetcher` - if you want it to be at the root, i.e. `http://mywebsite` then you can do this instead:

MyProject/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('WebFetcher/', include('Fetcher.urls')), # add the prefix here
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'), # move the home page path to the root urls.py
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Fetcher/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('page_objects/', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')
]
```

Comment: I posted a Edit 1 showing the current urls.py files I have that gave that error. Wish I had any web develop experience before this so I understood the urls.py better.

Comment: Why do you keep adding roots to your url that you place in the browser? How are you trying generating these urls? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebFetcher/WebFetcher/WebFetcher/page_objects/` - Just go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebFetcher/page_objects/`

Comment: I am not sure why it is doing it, that is the url that appears when I hit my form action. I will look around and see if I can find the cause.

Comment: I had FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/WebFetcher' in my settings.py I removed this and the 404 has been resolved thank you Daniel for all your help. Sorry for the dumb error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your urls.py path.

page_ojects should be page_objects

Comment: Thank you, that did not fix the issue but something I should have correct :)

Answer (score 0):

please write this pattern that will work fine.

```
path('page_ojects/', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')
```

Updated: add this code to your project level urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include

 urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('', include('Fetcher.urls')),
 ]
```

And if it doesn't solve your issue, then there might a issue in your views.py module, maybe your views doesn't find any correct views to dispatch. so write below code for testing purpose,in yours views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def page_objects(request):

return render("Hello, pages_objects!!")
```

Comment: I think Fetcher is your Django app,  WebFetcher is your Django project name. To access your Django apps urlpatterns you have to include the urls.py into project level urls.py module. like                                                                                         
from django.urls import path, inlcude

urlpatterns = [
    .................. # your admin route
    path('', include('Fetcher.urls')),
]

Comment: You are correct about the naming of the project, however I have already added that back when I was using a static form action. I added in the WebFetcher url.py so you can see it.